# Best approach optional settings jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a *very* simple jQuery plugin boilerplate:

```
var _defaults = {
  foo: false
};

function Plugin( settings ) {
  this.opts = $.extend( {}, _defaults, settings );
}
```

I have a `doSomething` method that can only run successfully if the option `foo` is set to `true` and there are other methods that may `doSomething()` at a certain point so I had a dilemma on where to place my `if` statement. First I thought:

```
Plugin.prototype = {
  doSomething: function() {
    // Do something that depends on foo
  },
  method: function() {
    ...
    if ( this.opts.foo ) { this.doSomething() }
  },
  method: function() {
    ...
    if ( this.opts.foo ) { this.doSomething() }
  }
};
```

But then for the sake of DRYness I decided to do this:

```
Plugin.prototype = {
  doSomething: function() {
    if ( this.opts.foo ) {
      // Do something that depends on foo
    }
  },
  method: function() {
    ...
    this.doSomething();
  },
  method: function() {
    ...
    this.doSomething();
  }
};
```

So now methods that may utilize `doSomething` run the function regardless of it being empty if `foo` is `false`.

So my question is, what is a better approach? The second one is shorter but it has to look-up the method everytime even if it's not necessary just to perhaps run an empty function. So is the first one more efficient?

Oh, and yes, I know probably this is micro-optimization and folks will say don't worry about it but I'm just curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a function will be more inefficient than your first approach.

Have a look at the tests here:
 http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/02/javascript-performance-hit-calling-function-vs-inline/

They confirm that function calls can be up to 50% slower on some browsers. You can test out your own.